# Puzzled about Chapter 3, section 3.12, of Jackson's famous book on Electrodynamics

Tags: electrostatics, greens-functions

I'm working through Jackson's book on E&M (3rd edition) and got stuck in section 3.12 on expansions of Green functions. I have three questions regarding section 3.12:

First, why is Jackson trying to find a Green function that satisfies equation 3.156? To my beginner mind, it seems incorrect to pursue 3.156 because I thought that Green's functions in electrostatics must always be limited to a lone Laplacian as prescribed in Jackson's equation 1.39, not eqn 3.156. Equation 3.156 seems drastically different than 1.39 due to the additional (f(x) + gamma)G term. Is Jackson making a mistake? What electrostatics geometry would create a need for equation 3.156? In all previous derivations of Green's functions for electrostatics, the process flows like this:
a) create a series expansion of 1/|x-x'| in the compatible coordinate system, wherein the series expansion converges to 1/|x-x'| in the domain
b) add a function F(x,x') that has Laplacian(F(x,x') = 0 to satisfy boundary conditions.

Second, why is "the z coordinate is singled out for special treatment" in equation 3.168? In that paragraph Jackson considers a rectangular box with sides at x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, x = a, y = b, z = c, and ALL of these planes need a boundary condition correct? So why single out just the z-dimension?

Third, can anyone give me some references that actually USE an equation like 3.168 of Jackson's section 3.12 (or a Green function for a box with all sides V=0)? This section 3.12 seems directionless and useless, but I'm a rookie so probably misunderstanding things.

Thank you all who can help.

[image: section 3.12 page 1]

[image: section 3.12 page 2]

[image: section 3.12 page 3]

Comment: He is just using those equations to illustrate the method of expanding the Green function as a superposition of eigenfunctions. I would assume this was a pedagogical choice since most readers would be familiar with the Schrödinger equation from a course on quantum mechanics.

Comment: Before Eq 3.161 he says "Specializing the foregoing considerations to the Poisson equation, we place $f(\mathbf{x})=0$ and $\lambda=0$ in (3.156)". Does this answer your first question?

Comment: For your 2nd and 3rd question, I think Jackson is demonstrating that the method works in a case where the algebra can be done explicitly (if laboriously); the method is more interesting than the actual result. In particular, the way I read it, Eq. 3.168 is meant to be interpreted as the result you would naturally get if you applied the methods in Sections 3.9 and 3.11 to rectangular coordinates, and Eq. 3.169 is the key identity that proves that the methods of 3.9 and 3.11 agree with the method of the current section (3.12). It's just an example used to show that everything is self-consistent.

Comment: Andrew, thanks, yes the "Specializing the foregoing considerations to the Poisson equation" is a good catch... so it appears the answer to my first question is: Jackson didn't intend equation 3.156 to ever be applicable to electrostatic problems.  Do you agree?  Thank you!

Comment: Andrew, regarding your first comment about eqn 3.161, it brings up another puzzle: why does Jackson use the wave-equation operator in eqn 3.161 when he immediately previously said he was setting gamm = 0 in order to make the operator relevant to Poisson's equation.  Shouldn't that k in eqn 3.161 be set to zero, because gamma = 0 so thus k must be zero?  In other words, the wave-equation operator doesn't seem to be compatible with an electrostatic Green's function (which holds that Laplacian(f) = -4 pi DiracDelta(x-x').

Comment: "Jackson didn't intend equation 3.156 to ever be applicable to electrostatic problems." -- I agree, and Jackson never claims otherwise, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Agreed, but Chapter 3 is smack in the middle of 173 pages (and four chapters) that are laser focussed on electrostatic problems with virtually no digressions away from that focus (other than this digression that we've identified now). Thus it seems highly IMPLIED that every paragraph is relevant to electrostatics problems.  Jackson doesn't clarify that he is taking a digression in eq 3.156 until WELL AFTER presenting equation 3.156.  Thus it seems a perfect recipe for creating confusion in students minds.   I forgive him of course, but I just like to call a spade a spade.

Comment: For your puzzle, note that under Eq 3.156 he says "where $\lambda$ is *not* equal to one of the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ in (3.154)". Think of $k^2$ in Eq 3.161 as being analogous to $\lambda_n$ in 3.154.

Comment: You've got to read everything carefully :)

Comment: Andrew, aha! You're unraveling the knot of my first question!  Thanks.

Comment: You start by discussing eqs. (3.156) and (1.39) but never show (1.39).

Comment: Green functions are simply much more general than the ones you initially encountered. Did you try reading the Wikipedia article about them?